# How commonly is the verb 'air' used in AmE?

Tags: verbs, expression-choice

One of the definitions Merriam-Webster gives for the verb 'air':

> to allow air from the outside to enter something (such as a room) so that it becomes fresher or cleaner

How common is this verb in (obviously colloquial) AmE speech? If it's not, what is the most common expression or verb?

My guess would be just 'let some fresh air in'.

Comment: I'd say fairly common. You'd say "air out this room" when the windows aren't open for example

Comment: We often will open a window to ***air out*** the room.  While i’m not fond of it several of my friends will ***air up*** their tires before going on a ride (bicycles) and at lunch people may ***air*** their grievances or their dirty laundry.

Comment: also, *air out* the house, the cabin  the car...

Comment: You mean like to "air your dirty laundry"?

Comment: @HotLicks what does that even mean?

Comment: @MichaelSmith - Did you Google it?

Comment: @HotLicks I get it now, thanks for another idiom under my belt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M-W says of this meaning of *air*: "often used with out"   and provides this example sentence:

> She opened the windows to air the room.

I would not use the verb *air* without *out*, so the sentence above would not be one that I would say.